# What to do if the corresponding authors do not share the referees' response?

Tags: publications, peer-review, advisor, ethics

My PhD advisers and I have an under review paper in a top tier journal. Recently, I received an email from the chief editor of the journal informing us that the paper has been reviewed and they encourage us to re-submit it.

After one week, I asked my advisers to share the response of the referees with me. Two weeks passed and I did not get a response. So, I sent another email and did not get a response yet.

To give a bit of background, I had informed my advisers that I don't have time to continue working on the paper. That said, it seems unreasonable to not share the referees' response with me (this is primarily my PhD work). I want this paper to be published.

I'm considering directly emailing the chief editor (cc'ing my advisers) and asking for the referees' comments. What do you suggest?

I would appreciate your thoughts and comments.

Edit: I got a response after several weeks. That said, as mentioned in the comment section, I successfully checked the reveiwer's response by logging in the journal website.

Comment: You sound contradictory. You want it published, but you don't want to work on it. What will you do if you get the referees' comments from the editor? Your advisors' behavior does not sound right, but neither sounds your approach. Imagine they want major revisions - what would you do? Also, for 2 weeks and 2 emails I think you are over-reacting.

Comment: You might check the journal's online submission system. Sometimes (often?) you will be able to see the records for any manuscripts you are associated with, including any reviews.

Comment: @avid Do you know of an example?

Comment: @user151413 I think I've done this in the past with journals using the ScholarOne system. However I don't have any current active submissions as non-corresponding author, so I can't now verify this.

Comment: Most journals now have an online submission system, and most journal webpage have a link to this system.  Access to the manuscript file *might* require a password or some other form of authentification provided to the corresponding author, so you might still be outta luck there if this was not shared.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Or, more likely, it is linked to the account of the corresponding author.

Comment: @user151413 American Physical Society does it with some manuscript # and name of 1st author; now whether or not the manuscript # was communicated to all authors is another matter but with APS it’s automatic.

Comment: If your co-authors are really ghosting you, then access to the referee report is the least of your worries - you can't publish the paper without the consent of your co-authors, and it sounds like in any case you wouldn't want to do it by yourself.  But unless there's already some bad blood between you and them, it seems unlikely they would intentionally ignore you.  More likely explanations are that they are busy, or disorganized, or are on vacation, or have had some sort of emergency.  I would just keep trying to contact them, perhaps through other means than email.

Comment: @avid. Yes, it did work. I just needed to log in to the journal account with my log in info. Thanks

Comment: @ZeroTheHero But this does not give you access to the reports, just a general history of what happened (sent for review, report received, etc., which the OP knows). With the APS, the corresponding author has to log in with their account to access the reports.

Comment: @user151413 I think you’re right..

Comment: @ZeroTheHero. It is perhaps journal dependent. In JMLR, I can see the report of all referees when I logged in. That is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @user2512443 nice.  That solves part of your problem then.

Comment: Just some possibilities that may or may not be realistic: Advisers get too many emails and this one was overlooked, or classified as spam (I had some pretty important emails classified as spam recently), or they are on holiday or ill? Some people in academia need to be shouted at to get a response out of them...

Comment: What @Lewian says. I know that September is the absolute peak of my educational tasks, and any other emails that I happen to receive in that month will take a back seat to those tasks. OP may be better served directly asking the editor for the referee reports.

Comment: Are you not getting a response at all, or are you getting a response that says "we can't give you the referee report"?